# Why did the IANA specifically choose these ranges for the the private IP address space?

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip-address, networking

10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 
172.16.0.0/12 IP addresses: 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 
192.168.0.0/16 IP addresses: 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

Is there any reason behind declaring these **particular ranges** as private IP addresses?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of historical trivia are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: This question was answered on https://superuser.com/q/784978/932793